# The fermi gas model of a nucleus

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, density-of-states, fermi-energy

In my nuclear physics lecture we learned about the "fermi gas modell" of a nucleus with which I have some problems. First the potential for the nucleons is shown in the picture below and it makes somewhat sense to me.

[image: potential as shown in lecture]

But now the lecture goes on and says, we use the model of the free nucleon gas. Why does that make sense? There is a potential so the nucleons aren't free at all. To me it looks much more similar to a particle in a box for example. 
So first question: **What das the free nucleon gas have to do with this potential?**

Putting that aside, the lecture goes on saying:

To calculate the fermi energy and the depth of the potential, we look at the number of possible states in  a volume V with a momentum between $p$ and d$p$:

$$dn=V\frac{4\pi p^2\text{d}p}{h^3}$$

My second question is: **Why is that true? Wher does this formular come from?**

Comment: This is  related: http://ictwiki.iitk.ernet.in/wiki/index.php/The_Fermi_gas_model and says that  in nuclear physics proton and neutrons are considered as moving quasi-freely within the nuclear volume. Apologies if you have read it already but it might explain where the gas idea comes from.

Comment: Free here means "non-interacting".

Comment: Ok, so free does not mean, that the potential is ignored! I was confused there.

Comment: Any help with the second question?

Answer (score 1):

1. "As spin-1/2 particles they naturally obey Fermi-Dirac statistics. It is assumed that the nucleon, inside those constraints imposed by the Paul I principle, can move freely inside the nuclear volume" Povh Particles and nuclei. Basically the potential is flat and nucleons are free inside the nuclei
2. By the uncertainty principle ( Delta x Delta p >= hbar/2) one state occupies at least  Delta x Delta p / (hbar/2) in 2D phase space . Here are are considering 3 spatial dimensions (x y z) and hence 6D phase space . Hence n = Volume_space x Volume_momentum_space  / (hbar/2)^3 
   The factors of 2 pi in the denominator come from some more rigorous treatment I think, but you get the idea I hope. For the momentum phase space we consider a spherical shell.