# Can quarks in a proton be modeled as a Fermi gas?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, fermions, quarks, fermi-energy

I recently learned in one of my courses that a nucleus could be modeled as a Fermi gas. This led me to think about other fermions and whether or not I could mess around with them as well. Are the binding forces between quarks too strong for us to be able to imagine them as a "non-interacting" gas? Does the mass of the down quark being significantly larger relative to the up quark prevent this from working? I have a basic understanding of quarks so there could be all sorts of reasons why it couldn't work I don't know of, but I would be interested in why this is not (or why this is) possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, hadrons are decisively different than  [nuclei](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/317315/the-fermi-gas-model-of-a-nucleus?rq=1). For the Fermi gas model you want weakly interacting fermion constituents.

For a proton, instead, density of states is hardly meaningful: you have zillions of virtual quarks, antiquarks, and gluons (bosons!), barely excluding each other, while the three valence quarks contribute [less than 1%](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/31465/if-quarks-didnt-have-mass-could-protons-and-neutrons-exist?rq=1) to the proton mass. At short distances, they are weakly interacting, by dint of the asymptotic freedom of gluons interactions; but near the hadron radius, of the order of a fermi, the effective interaction strength explodes to infinity. I've never heard about a Fermi gas shortcut for hadron masses.